# using sed with ? (question mark) special character

Tags: sed, character

I have an infected website, and I am trying to clean it out using sed. Unfortunately I am unable to escape the question mark sign in the URL and I am really stuck here. I've searched over the web for a possible solution, but unfortunately I didn't found a proper way to do so.

Just an explanation:

The injected code is similar to this one:

```
< iframe src=http://test.com/index.html?i=23123>< /iframe>
```

Note that I am not a pro, and there is why I need your help!

so my way to clear the code is :

```
sed -i '/< iframe src=http:\/\/test.com\/index.html\?i=23123>/,/< \/iframe>/d' index.html
```

Unfortunately that didn't help as well as all others.

All help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: what does "that didn't help as well as all others" mean? tell us what works, what doesn't and how it should be better.

Comment: Also notice how few followers there are on most of the tags you have assigned to your question. Better to include a tag for the OS you are using. Also edit you question to include the output of `sed --version` (you may just get an error msg). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "< iframe src=http://test.com/index.html?i=23123>< /iframe>" \
| sed 's@< iframe src=http://test.com/index.html?i=23123>< /iframe>@@'
```

Produces no output, which to me means this is successfully deleting your problem string.

Note that most seds will accept an alternate regex-replacement character, here I am using `@` because there are no `@`s in the search target. On some seds, you have to tell it 'hey I'm using an alternate, and escape the char, like `s\@.....@@`.

I don't see why your attempt to quote the `?` is failing. Did you try `[?]` and (worst case) `[\?]`. Are there 2nd level evaluations happening by the shell that you're not mentioning here? Does my simple example also fail?

As others will certainly tell you, your approach is strictly a bandaid, you need to figure out what the security hole is in your system and fix it. Your pages will get corrupted again.

Comment: [?] worked! Anyway, I found the problem in a outdated plugin. Thanks for sharing :-)